# Why would a video play fine on a 3G iOS device but not on a 2G?

Tags: ios, video, 3g

I've had a contractor compress a video to be used in an app we're developing and while the video plays just fine on a 3G device, artifacts appear when watched on a 2G device. Why would this be? The 2G device is a 3.1.3 version.

Comment: The first thing I can think of is quality and bit rate may be too high.  The video may not have been compressed enough to be played on the 2G's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with a mixture of network speed and hardware. Take a look at wired's comparison: http://www.wired.com/reviews/2011/02/verizon-iphone/

Same exact phone, but since ATT's network is faster, the Verizon phone plays a less quality video.

It's probably going to be difficult to get a good looking video over 2G. Also, is it even worth it? How many phones are still 2G? I can't imagine that many.

Comment: Thanks. In general you're right about not many 2G phones around compared to 3 and 4, but we have a substantial 2G audience using our app and we're wanting to update with more vids without excluding them.

Comment: I'm curious as to what is substantial. The 2G phone is over 3.5 years old and was discontinued over 2.5 years ago. Most people upgrade every 2 years. So even at the end of its product cycle, they phone should be outdated. Just for my own curiosity what is substantial? I know on our sites/apps we have about 1% of 2G use.

Comment: We've got about 2.2% of 2G use.  Perhaps substantial isn't the word I should have used, however in real terms it's a fairly large number of people.

Comment: Jamie, would you suggest 2.2% not being enough to worry about?  It's a few thousand people.  Compared to the rest, yes, it's small.  But to exclude them... do you think it would be a bad move or a necessary one?  I'm not sure, myself.

Comment: Where I work we are government funded and we do not have to support anything that has less than 10% usage. The 2.2% of your people that are using 2G are costing you more money than necessary. You have to look at it from a ROI (Return on Investment). Is the time you are putting into this worth the headaches and the time for just the 2.2%. I know that up until recently we had to support IE6 & 7, now those are less than 10%, so we tell people they need to upgrade. I say it's a necessary move to exclude them. Having to make an inferior product (lower quality video) for 2.2% is not fair to 97.8%